# is it possible to hack a server motherboard to support two desktop CPUs

Tags: central-processing-unit

Is it possible to install or hack two desktop CPUs, e.g. two Core i7 instead of two Xeon into a server motherboard? If not why?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the processor to be usable in a multi-socket configuration, it must expose the [QuickPath Interconnect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_QuickPath_Interconnect) externally. Intel desktop processors do not do so.

You'll need to use a Xeon, and not just any Xeon; some of the lower end ones can only be used in single socket configurations. Check its specifications at [Intel's ARK site](http://ark.intel.com/) to make sure that it can be used in a multi-socket board. For modern processors, this will be listed as Scalability with a value of e.g. 1S, 2S or 4S (sockets).

Comment: thanks. The "QuickPath Interconnect" information is what I was looking for. Not sure why womble decide to downgrade the question